# php combine/merge elements in dynamic array

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have an array from post form, the inputs turned to an array and It has one element at least. It look like this:

```
'saleTimes' => 
 array 
  0 => 
    array (size=9)
      'sunSale' => int 0
      'monSale' => string '1' (length=1)
      'tueSale' => int 0
      'wedSale' => int 0
      'thuSale' => int 0
      'friSale' => int 0
      'satSale' => int 0
      'startSaleTime' => string '09:00' (length=5)
      'endSaleTime' => string '15:00' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=9)
      'sunSale' => int 0
      'monSale' => int 0
      'tueSale' => string '1' (length=1)
      'wedSale' => int 0
      'thuSale' => int 0
      'friSale' => int 0
      'satSale' => int 0
      'startSaleTime' => string '05:19' (length=5)
      'endSaleTime' => string '08:00' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=9)
      'sunSale' => int 0
      'monSale' => int 0
      'tueSale' => string '1' (length=1)
      'wedSale' => int 0
      'thuSale' => int 0
      'friSale' => int 0
      'satSale' => string '1' (length=1)
      'startSaleTime' => string '05:19' (length=5)
      'endSaleTime' => string '08:00' (length=5)
   .....
```

I want to merge elements to one, the result will be this:

```
array (size=9)
  'sunSale' => int 0
  'monSale' => string '1' (length=1)
  'tueSale' => string '1' (length=1)
  'wedSale' => int 0
  'thuSale' => int 0
  'friSale' => int 0
  'satSale' => string '1' (length=1)
```

AND according to an array:

```
$weekName = array(
    'sunSale' => '星期日',
    'monSale' => '星期一',
    'tueSale' => '星期二',
    'wedSale' => '星期三',
    'thuSale' => '星期四',
    'friSale' => '星期五',
    'satSale' => '星期六',
);
```

It will remain `weeks` index which has value `string '1'`, and `startSaleTime`、`endSaleTime` is no use, keep them in array or remove them 
does not affect the result.

I tried this

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($weekName); $i++) {
       array_merge($paramList['saleTimes'][$i], (int)$paramList['saleTimes'][$i+1]);
    }
```

but will get error `Argument #1 is not an array`,
how can I get the all `weeks` index with value 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can simply pass each single sub-array to `array_merge()` as Arguments without the need for a Loop. However, it is good to remember that for an `array_merge()`, the values of the later Array will override those of Previous one, so it is important that the array whose Data you are most interested in comes last. The Code below demonstrates this Point. A [Quick-Test Here](https://eval.in/678472):

**THE GIVEN ARRAY:**

```
<?php
    $arr        = array(
        array(
          'sunSale' =>  0,
          'monSale' => '1',
          'tueSale' =>  0,
          'wedSale' =>  0,
          'thuSale' =>  0,
          'friSale' =>  0,
          'satSale' =>  0,
          'startSaleTime' => '09:00',
          'endSaleTime' => '15:00',
        ),
        array (
          'sunSale' =>  0,
          'monSale' =>  0,
          'tueSale' => '1',
          'wedSale' =>  0,
          'thuSale' =>  0,
          'friSale' =>  0,
          'satSale' =>  0,
          'startSaleTime' => '05:19',
          'endSaleTime' => '08:00',
        ),
        array (
          'sunSale' =>  0,
          'monSale' =>  0,
          'tueSale' => '1',
          'wedSale' =>  0,
          'thuSale' =>  0,
          'friSale' =>  0,
          'satSale' => '1',
          'startSaleTime' => '05:19',
          'endSaleTime' => '08:00',
        ),
    );
```

**THE MERGE:**

```
<?php
    $arrMerged  = array_merge($arr[0], $arr[1], $arr[2]);

    var_dump($arrMerged);
```

**THE DUMP RESULT:**

```
    // var_dump($arrMerged) ABOVE YIELDS::      
    array (size=9)
      'sunSale' => int 0
      'monSale' => int 0
      'tueSale' => string '1' (length=1)
      'wedSale' => int 0
      'thuSale' => int 0
      'friSale' => int 0
      'satSale' => string '1' (length=1)
      'startSaleTime' => string '05:19' (length=5)
      'endSaleTime' => string '08:00' (length=5)
```

> **UPDATE: USING A LOOP (MANUAL MERGING).** ([QUICK-TEST HERE.](https://eval.in/678479))

```
<?php

    $merged     = $arr[0];

    foreach($arr as $item){
        foreach($item as $key=>$val){
            $merged[$key] = ($merged[$key] == "" || !$merged[$key])?$val : $merged[$key];
        }
    }
    // REMOVE THE `startSaleTime` AND `endSaleTime` KEYS
    unset($merged['startSaleTime']);
    unset($merged['endSaleTime']);

    var_dump($merged);
    // YIELDS::
    array (size=7)
      'sunSale' => int 0
      'monSale' => string '1' (length=1)
      'tueSale' => string '1' (length=1)
      'wedSale' => int 0
      'thuSale' => int 0
      'friSale' => int 0
      'satSale' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Comment: but I cant control the array elements will  be one or two .. , like `array_merge($arr[0])` or  `array_merge($arr[0], $arr[1].... $arr[4])` depends on the post. so I have to count the array first?

Comment: @DoranWu   Then You may manually merge those using a Loop. The Post was updated to reflect that approach: https://eval.in/678479

Comment: THX! @Poiz It was what I want :)

Comment: @DoranWu    Happy it worked for you :-) You may as well mark the Post as the Correct Answer...

Comment: @DoranWu    **:-)**